# Propositional Logic - How to prove that A implies itself?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, proof-theory, hilbert-calculus

I'm trying to form a propositional logic proof chain for the tautology $\delta \implies \delta$, using only the axioms

1. $\alpha \implies (\beta \implies \alpha)$
2. $((\alpha\implies (\beta \implies\gamma))\implies((\alpha\implies\beta)\implies(
   \alpha\implies\gamma)))$
3. $((\neg\beta\implies\neg\alpha)\implies(\alpha\implies\beta))$

The only rule of inference is modus ponens.  Seems like it should be easy, but I can't seem to get it.  Help appreciated.

Comment: Just a guess, but could choosing $\beta=\alpha$ work?

Comment: Why do you want to prove such an obvious claim using such artificial axioms ? Please motivate it.

Comment: Is there a name for this collection of axioms?  I've seen a bunch of questions like this, and I'm interested in reading more about it!

Comment: It's the Hilbert system of axioms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. $(A\to((A\to A)\to A))\to((A\to(A\to A))\to(A\to A))$ - Axiom 2
2. $A\to ((A\to A)\to A)$ - Axiom 1
3. $(A\to(A\to A))\to(A\to A)$ - MP from 1 and 2
4. $(A\to(A\to A))$ - Axiom 1
5. $A\to A$ - MP from 3 and 4